# Cumulative product of (1-previous_record)*current_record

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, rolling-computation, accumulate

The data frame contains two variables (`time` and `rate`) and 10 observations

```
time <- seq(1:10) 
rate <- 1-(0.99^time)
dat <- data.frame(time, rate)
```

I need to add a new column (called `new_rate`).

`new_rate` is defined as follows

Note: `new_rate_1` is the first observation of new the column new_rate, etc.

```
new_rate_1 = rate_1
new_rate_2 = (1-rate_1)*rate_2
new_rate_3 = (1-rate_1)*(1-rate_2)*rate_3
new_rate_4 = (1-rate_1)*(1-rate_2)*(1-rate_3)*rate_4
...
new_rate_10 = (1-rate_1)*(1-rate_2)*(1-rate_3)*(1-rate_4)*(1-rate_5)*(1-rate_6)*(1-rate_7)*(1-rate_8)*(1-rate_9)*rate_10
```

How this can be done in **base R** or `dplyr`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cumprod` to the rescue (hat-tip to [@Cole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11355066/cole) for simplifying the code):

```
dat$rate * c(1, cumprod(1 - head(dat$rate, -1)))
```

The logic is that you are essentially doing a `cum`ulative `prod`uct of `1 - dat$rate`, multiplied by the current step.
At the first step, you can just keep the existing value, but then you need to offset the two vectors so that the multiplication gives the desired result.

Proof:

```
out <- c(
dat$rate[1],
(1-dat$rate[1])*dat$rate[2],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*dat$rate[3],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*(1-dat$rate[3])*dat$rate[4],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*(1-dat$rate[3])*(1-dat$rate[4])*dat$rate[5],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*(1-dat$rate[3])*(1-dat$rate[4])*(1-dat$rate[5])*dat$rate[6],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*(1-dat$rate[3])*(1-dat$rate[4])*(1-dat$rate[5])*(1-dat$rate[6])*dat$rate[7],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*(1-dat$rate[3])*(1-dat$rate[4])*(1-dat$rate[5])*(1-dat$rate[6])*(1-dat$rate[7])*dat$rate[8],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*(1-dat$rate[3])*(1-dat$rate[4])*(1-dat$rate[5])*(1-dat$rate[6])*(1-dat$rate[7])*(1-dat$rate[8])*dat$rate[9],
(1-dat$rate[1])*(1-dat$rate[2])*(1-dat$rate[3])*(1-dat$rate[4])*(1-dat$rate[5])*(1-dat$rate[6])*(1-dat$rate[7])*(1-dat$rate[8])*(1-dat$rate[9])*dat$rate[10]
)

all.equal(
  dat$rate * c(1, cumprod(1 - head(dat$rate, -1))),
  out
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward math approach using `cumprod` should work

```
> c(1, head(cumprod(1 - rate), -1)) * rate
 [1] 0.01000000 0.01970100 0.02881885 0.03709807 0.04432372 0.05033049
 [7] 0.05500858 0.05830607 0.06022773 0.06083074
```

---

If you want to practice with recursions, you can try the method below

```
f <- function(v, k = length(v)) {
    if (k == 1) {
        return(v[k])
    }
    u <- f(v, k - 1)
    c(u, tail(u, 1) * (1 / v[k - 1] - 1) * v[k])
}
```

such that

```
> f(rate)
 [1] 0.01000000 0.01970100 0.02881885 0.03709807 0.04432372 0.05033049
 [7] 0.05500858 0.05830607 0.06022773 0.06083074
```

Comment: To me this approach is best.  Simple and straight.  Needless to say +1 already

Comment: but I haven't answered this! :D

Comment: @AnilGoyal haha, my bad. I took the answer by Anoushiravan R as yours

Comment: @AnilGoyal If you have any idea to this question, you are always welcome to share your answer :P

Comment: I would have used `cumprod()` way to solve this one.  That's why I like yours. :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still interested in how to do it with `purrr::reduce` family of functions. Here are two solutions:

- In every iteration if you multiply the accumulated/previous value by (1/previous value of rate - 1) * (current value of rate) you will get the desired output in every row

```
library(purrr)

accumulate2(dat$rate[-nrow(dat)], dat$rate[-1], .init = dat$rate[1], 
           ~ ..1 * (1/..2 - 1) * ..3) %>%
  simplify()

 [1] 0.01000000 0.01970100 0.02881885 0.03709807 0.04432372 0.05033049 0.05500858 0.05830607
 [9] 0.06022773 0.06083074
```

And also in ****base R**** we could do the following:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {
  x * (1/dat$rate[y - 1] - 1) * dat$rate[y]
}, init = dat$rate[1], 
seq_len(nrow(dat))[-1], accumulate = TRUE)

 [1] 0.01000000 0.01970100 0.02881885 0.03709807 0.04432372 0.05033049 0.05500858 0.05830607
 [9] 0.06022773 0.06083074
```